# ¿Como pudo hacer una sumar un valor con funciones en Tkinter? basicamente no esta sumando como deberia

Tags: python, tkinter

///esta es la funcion de agregar dulces que creo que me da los problemas///

```
#funcion de agregar dulces
def agregar_dulces(almacen, x):
    x = int(caja_de_texto.get())
    almacen = almacen + x
    caja_de_texto.delete(0, "end")


#funcion de mostrar dulces
def mostrar_dulces(almacen):
    etiqueta["text"] = almacen
    etiqueta.pack()
```

///aqui estan los botones///[image: en la primera imagen es mostrado el numero de dulces para agregar "12" pero no se suma y muestra que hay "0 dulces almacenados"]

```
#declaracion de botones
boton_vender = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "Vender", command = lambda: vender_dulces)
boton_agregar = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "Agregar", command = lambda: agregar_dulces(almacen, x)) 
boton_mostar= tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "Mostrar", command = lambda: mostrar_dulces(almacen))
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código mínimo necesario para reproducir tu problema y arregla la indentación de las funciones. Saludos

Comment: Te olvidaste de llamar a vender_dulces dentro del lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es mejor que trabajes con una variable local para conocer la cantidad de dulces así la llamas dentro de las funciones con global
aquí mi solución siguiendo tu diseño, Saludos :)

empezamos creando la ventana y sus cosas

```
from tkinter import *

#ventana
root = Tk()
root.title('venta de dulces')
root.geometry('400x400')

#contador de dulces global 
dulces=0

#label que muestra la cantidad de dulces
cantidad_dulces = Label(root, text='Tienes 0 Dulces')
cantidad_dulces.pack(fill=X)
cantidad_dulces.config(background='cyan')

#entry para las operaciones
entry_dulces = Entry(root, text='')
entry_dulces.pack(pady=10)

#botones
boton_agregar = Button(root, text='Agregar Dulces', command=lambda: Agregar_Dulces())
boton_agregar.pack(pady=10)
boton_vender = Button(root, text='Vender Dulces', command=lambda: Vender_Dulces() )
boton_vender.pack(pady=10)
boton_mostrar = Button(root, text='Mostrar Dulces', command=lambda: Mostrar_Dulces() )
boton_mostrar.pack(pady=10)
```

Debes coloca global y la variable de los dulces para evitar el error UnboundLocalError y esto pasa porque se hace referencia de manera incorrecta, a una variable local no asignada

```
def Agregar_Dulces():
    global dulces
    dulces = dulces + int(entry_dulces.get())
    cantidad_dulces['text'] = 'has agregado dulces y tienes : '+str(dulces)
    entry_dulces.delete(0, 'end')


def Vender_Dulces():
    global dulces

    #casos imposibles al vender
    if dulces== 0:
         cantidad_dulces['text'] = 'Tienes 0 dulces no puedes vender' 

    elif dulces < int(entry_dulces.get()):
        cantidad_dulces['text'] = 'No tienes los dulces necesarios'

    else:
        dulces = dulces - int(entry_dulces.get())
        cantidad_dulces['text'] = 'has vendido dulces y tienes : '+str(dulces)
        entry_dulces.delete(0, 'end')

def Mostrar_Dulces():
    global dulces
    cantidad_dulces['text'] = 'Tienes en total '+str(dulces)+' dulces'
    
root.mainloop()
```

Cabe resaltar que funciona parcialmente ya que marca errores que solo se muestran en consola al poner letras en el entry o al intentar vender y agregar valores vacíos.